# Docker Desktop Community for Windows | Container Caching

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Does Docker Desktop Community version for Windows caches the containers?

I was removing some of my containers and then trying to compose them again for a Python 3/Flask/Angular 7 application and it was turning them up without installing dependencies pretty fast. I had to remove containers then restart my machine for it to build the containers again.

I was running this command:

docker-compose up --build

Yes I have a docker-compose.yml. I also have Dockerfile with commands to install the dependencies.

FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/flask

## Update working directory

WORKDIR /var/www/flask

## copy everything from this directory to server/flask docker container

COPY . /var/www/flask/

## Give execute permission to below file, so that the script can be executed

by docker.
RUN chmod +x /var/www/flask/entrypoint.sh

## Install the Python libraries

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

## COPY uswgi.ini

COPY ./uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi.ini

EXPOSE 5000

## run server

CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]

I also tried following commands:

docker system prune

docker-compose up --build --force-recreate

Comment: What commands exactly were you running?  At what point in the sequence do you expect dependencies to be reinstalled?  Do you have a `Dockerfile` and/or `docker-compose.yml` that's relevant to this setup?